# Prove that Conjugation in $S_4$ Permutes the Elements in a Subgroup X

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question I'm doing is asking me to prove that conjugation in the group $S_4$ permutes elements in the subset $X-{1}$, where $X$ is the subgroup {$1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)$}

My question is that simply enough I don't know what the question is asking of me it makes no sense in my head.  I know that two elements $a, b\in S_4$ are conjugate if there exists $\sigma \in S_4$ such that $a=\sigma b\sigma^{-1}$.  Can someone try to explain the question to me please?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Show that if $a$ is an element of $X$, then its conjugate $\sigma a \sigma^{-1}$ is also an element of $X$ for any $\sigma\in S_4$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense I understand completely now thank you very much!

Comment: In general, when we say that $G$ 'permutes the elements of $X$ by conjugation', we mean that when $G$ conjugates the elements of $X$, they stay in $X$.  They don't leave $X$.